# Create a XML file out of a SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xml, dom

I want to create a XML file out of a SQL Query. But my problem is, that it fails every time... This is my code:

```
$stln = $database->query('SELECT name FROM `wp_all_import_xml` GROUP BY name');

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;

while($row = $stln->fetch_row()){
    $product = $dom->createElement('product');
    $title = $dom->createElement('title');
    $title->nodeValue = $row["name"][0];
    $product->appendChild($title);
    $dom->appendChild($product);
}

$dom->save('httpdocs/cronjob/data/cronjob.xml');
```

The cronjob.xml file should look like this at the end:

```
<product>
    <title>iPhone 7</title>
</product>
<product>
    <title>iPhone 6</title>
</product>
<product>
    <title>iPhone 5</title>
</product>
```

But every time I end up with an empty XML file which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

And my browser is telling me this by calling the cronjob.xml file:

This page contains the following errors:

error on line 5 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Does anybody knows where is my error and how I can fix it?

**UPDATE:**
The XML file gets created correctly. And I see the titles. But there is another problem... Namely, that I get errors like that:

```
PHP Warning:  main(): unterminated entity reference            Evil in /Users/spacer/Desktop/spacer/Test/spiel.php on line 21
PHP Warning:  main(): unterminated entity reference   Scenario Pack in /Users/spacer/Desktop/spacer/Test/spiel.php on line 21
PHP Warning:  main(): unterminated entity reference  Conquer The Ultimate Collection in /Users/spacer/Desktop/spacer/Test/spiel.php on line 21
PHP Warning:  main(): unterminated entity reference         Mystics in /Users/spacer/Desktop/spacer/Test/spiel.php on line 21
```

For example. A name where this happens is a name like this: `Csx Nre 3Gs 21B Genset & New Haven Fl9 Twin Pack`. But I do not know, why he cannot handle this name..

Any idea?

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: Xml cannot look like your example, it's not a valid xml (more than 1 root element).

Comment: So what I'm forced to change?

Comment: You need to check that you're actually fetching products. I cannot be sure, because too much code is missing, but it is quite possible your XML doesn't contain any products because you haven't fetched any. For instance, in some cases you have to `execute()` a query before you can fetch the results.

Comment: Why XML? Is anyone still using that?

Comment: @FrazeJr. If you cannot have multiple root elements, then using common sense what do think you need to change?

Comment: I found the error... I updated the question. Because I don't know what PHP want...

Answer (score 0):

As Mateusz Sip said you cannot have multiple root elements, try something like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products>
   <product>
       <title>iPhone 7</title>
   </product>
   <product>
       <title>iPhone 6</title>
   </product>
   <product>
       <title>iPhone 5</title>
   </product>
</products>
```

Comment: I found the error... I updated the question. Because I don't know what PHP want...